# fopen incompatible type char (*)[9] instead of char(*) in C

Tags: c, char, fopen

My program in C reads data in a file in order to initialise variables but it won't open the file. It fails when it reaches fopen. Xcode outputs the following warning for both fopen and printf. I understand the error but I don't know how to correct it, I tried many tricks but it won't do, can anyone help me out ? I just want my program to open *Try1.txt*.

*Incompatible pointer types passing 'char (*)[9]' to parameter of type const char*'*

So this is the code inside my main function :

```
FILE *infile = NULL;
const char infilename [] = "Try1.txt";

infile = fopen(&infilename, "r");
if (infile == NULL)
{
    printf("Failed to open file: %s\n", &infilename);
    return 1;
}
```

Note that the program stops before reaching the if loop because it never prints. I tried to initialise the size and to add '\0' at the end of my string too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because of `&infilename`, which gives you a pointer to the array of characters. Drop the address-of operator and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

### Problem

`&infilename` is a pointer to the array, which means it is a pointer to an object of type `char (*)[9]`.

But, `infilename` will be a pointer of type `char (*)`, which points to the first element of the array.

### Fix

```
infile = fopen(infilename, "r");
```